# Setup WSO2 EMM with Stripe

Tags: wso2, stripe-payments, wso2-iot

I'm trying to setup my MDM vendor with WSO2 MDM server. It's pretty straight forward on the MDM part. However, I'm at a lost when I'm trying to add Stripe payment to my setup. Basically, I'm setting up an MDM vendor and the vendor will take payment from customer through Stripe. I looked and WSO2 has ESB that can integrate with Stripe. I'm pretty new with this and I'm not sure how they all work together. I'm not sure how they work together as a whole system. Can someone please give me a big picture on how I can setup my system that has a WSO2 MDM (EMM) server, Stripe, and able to take payment?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Exact use case which you are trying to address is not clear. Let me explain some of the facts which might be important so as to finalize your scenario. In your case, if you are referring something related to application management. WSO2 EMM is used [WSO2 APPM](http://wso2.com/products/app-manager/) in orde to manage applications which include iOS,Andriod, and Windows where you need to customize if is to be gone through ESB.Then you need to configure [Stripe Connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Stripe+Operations) with ESB which route all the requests through Stripe payment gateway.

If you can explain use case which you are trying out we may help on that.